# Where can i find the code about move_group_interface.plan method?

Tags: ros2, moveit

I'm studying moveit.
A trajectory was created through a method called plan, but I couldn't find the process, so I asked a question.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be in the MoveIt GitHub repository. More specifically, you can find it [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/4c024bc49ef20369f01d363c5884556932bf86da/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L636) in the `move_group_interface.cpp` file. In simple terms, this method prepares the action goal, sends the goal, and handles the result.

The function takes only a reference to the `Plan` object, and the process does not really tell you what is happening under the hood. For a deeper understanding of how the motion planning request is constructed, look into the `constructMotionPlanRequest` function too. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/4c024bc49ef20369f01d363c5884556932bf86da/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1012).

Comment: As far as req, thank you for your attention to detail.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information to go on with, I'm not sure if you are using C++ or Python. However, the `plan` function can be found [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/4c024bc49ef20369f01d363c5884556932bf86da/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L636). In case you are looking for a Python equivalent, AFAIK the MoveIt python variant is a wrapper around the original CPP library, so I'm guessing any call to `plan` will come down to this function.